# Why does my flapdoodle Embedded MongoDB test fail to run? (creating 'embeddedMongoServer' could not start process EOF)

Tags: mongodb, maven, spring-boot, spring-test, embedded-database

I'm having trouble getting my brand new project to build. I used https://start.spring.io/ to generate a fresh new Spring 2.0 MongoDB Maven project, and I want to have an embedded MongoDB database for my integration tests. The spring initializer added a dependency for de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo to that end.

But every time I try to run a "mvn clean package", I get the following error during my test:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path resource
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: 
Could not start process: <EOF>
at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.AbstractMongoProcess.onAfterProcessStart(AbstractMongoProcess.java:79) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.3.jar:na]
at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.AbstractProcess.<init>(AbstractProcess.java:116) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-2.0.2.jar:na]
at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.AbstractMongoProcess.<init>(AbstractMongoProcess.java:53) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.3.jar:na]
at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodProcess.<init>(MongodProcess.java:50) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.3.jar:na]
at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable.start(MongodExecutable.java:44) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.3.jar:na]
at de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable.start(MongodExecutable.java:34) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo-2.0.3.jar:na]
at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Executable.start(Executable.java:108) ~[de.flapdoodle.embed.process-2.0.2.jar:na]
```

What am I missing?

My Application file is pretty straightforward:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NewnewinternetApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NewnewinternetApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Config file is very simple:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.snoop.dougg.newnewinternet")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I have two simple controllers returning just static output for now.

I have a little document:

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.username = username;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //Getters, setters, and equals and hash code methods...
}
```

And then a silly little test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@SpringBootTest -> Doesn't work either
@DataMongoTest
public class NewnewinternetApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Test
    public void sillyLittleTest() {
        mongoTemplate.save(new User("sdoug", "Snoop", "Dougg"));
        Assert.notNull(
            mongoTemplate.find(
                new Query(Criteria.where("firstName").is("Snoop")), User.class),
            "Couldn't find by first name!");
    }
}
```

And then my pom file, which I really just left alone:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.snoop.dougg.newnewinternet</groupId>
    <artifactId>NewNewInternet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>NewNewInternet</name>
    <description>A new new internet</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <azure.version>2.0.1</azure.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

Answer (score 7):

Commenting out the following lines in application.properties and placing them in a different profile can also work. I found it [here](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/issues/287#issuecomment-560767861)

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=
spring.data.mongodb.host=
spring.data.mongodb.port=
```

Comment: This causes a `Database name must not be empty!` error log in my project.

Answer (score 6):

I was in the same situation, and I could resolve it using @DirtiesContext on this way:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class CommoditiesApplicationTests {

}
```

Comment: It doesn't help as well.

Answer (score 5):

my error message was exactly like this

```
2022-03-15 10:57:00.053  WARN 7196 --- [    Test worker] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'embeddedMongoServer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfig]: Factory method 'embeddedMongoConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Set the spring.mongodb.embedded.version property or define your own MongodConfig bean to use embedded MongoDB
```

so, I add property in my application.yml file.

```
spring.mongodb.embedded.version: 3.2.3
```

and, solved it.

Comment: This one worked for me... I don't know why, but it worked. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me too... I also don't understand why.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the 32 bit mongodb client was downloaded instead of the 64 bit one.
embedded.mongo library uses [BitSize](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.process/blob/master/src/main/java/de/flapdoodle/embed/process/distribution/BitSize.java) class to determine the OS architecture. In my system `System.getProperty("os.arch")` was not returning a value listed in the `if` statement.
I solved the problem by setting `os.arch` system property to `x86_64` (one of the values used by `BitSize` to return `B64`) in my application main.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("os.arch", "x86_64");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Note: `System.getProperty("os.arch")` will return the wrong value if you use a 32 bit java version to run your application on a 64 bit system!

Comment: I needed to add the below on @BeforeAll to make the tests pass on my m1 mac:
System.setProperty("os.arch", "x86_64");

Answer (score 3):

Usually already running mongodb instance is the source of the issue. I would start with checking if anything occupies default mongodb port - 27017.

Answer (score 2):

chances are the instance of mongodb downloaded through the spring plugin is 32 & you are running on 64 bit java or vice versa. Please confirm if there is any other way you have identified the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the pretty same scenario here, and solved it using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
        <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

instead of `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the socket file was still around.

To get to the underlying issue, I wanted the console logging output, I put a breakpoint in the `else` clause of the  `AbstractMongoProcess::onAfterProcessStart` (which is hit on failure).
Here you have access to the `logWatch` and can run a `System.out.println(logWatch.output.toString());` in debug mode to get the mongo console out. For my issue, the output said `SocketException: Address already in use`

Trying commands suggested such as `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P` did not work for me (nothing listed in my case)

I found another SO answer  that said to run `ls -lrta /tmp | grep .sock`

The .sock file was still there from a previous run (Apparently I had interrupted my tests)

Deleting this file solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the package de.flapdoodle.embed which was used for Embedded Mongo, use a stable version of it 3.5.0

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

add it in the pom.file(add the version to it).Then update maven it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

My case was a bit special, but maybe this help someone else too to resolve this.

If, by any chance, you are using win 10 and you have already a MongoDB running as a service (in my case it was an earlier version - v3.4 - running), then try to stop the service, and run the test afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@DirtiesContext` to the test class level.

Comment: It doesn't help.

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the 'mongo' dir in my appdata/temp and that is when I caught my McAfee quarantining my embedded mongo. I turned OFF McAfee and deleted the temp mongo again and then all ran great...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.
**spring.data.mongodb.port** was **27017** in application.properties. I changed it to **0**. When **0** is used, a random port is assigned instead.

My Integration Test is like below:

```
        @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
        @DataMongoTest
        public class IntegrationTestIT { ... }
```

I'm using de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:3.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Refer to this github issue for the solution if your problem is related to flapdoodle: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/issues/427

Just increase the **flapdoodle version >=3.5.0**
and if possible increase also spring-boot version to the latest